# Changing image Appearance and BorderStyle only works sometimes?

Tags: image, vb6

I'm trying to use the `Appearance` and `BorderStyle` properties of the image control to provide a not selected/selected indicator.

After image is loaded and displayed in the not selected condition, I can change `Appearance` and `BorderStyle` to `1` and it displays properly. **But subsequent changes of these properties back to `0` has no effect**.

```
Public Sub SelectPic(obj As Object, SelectIt As Boolean)
Dim Val As Integer
  If SelectIt Then
    Val = 1 'this works
  Else
    Val = 0 'this doesn't work
  End If
  obj.Appearance = Val
  obj.BorderStyle = Val
  obj.Refresh
End Sub
```

If I load a .bmp file into an image with flat appearance and no border, the image displays in agreement with the .bmp sizing info. But if load into an image with 3D appearance and single border, it displays according to the defined image size. Changing the properties back to flat and no border has no effect.